# TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, mocha.js

- i am trying to write a test case for a jsx file
- in this I am able to pass proptypes...
- but not where I have passed proptypes propely...
- i am getting an error when i run my test case..
- providing my error, test case and code below...
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
- not sure how to make it work with this exists..
- its happing at this function dispatchSidebarExists..
- can you tell me how should i need to put it in my test case

javascript
**error**

```
 1) shallow renderer tests for sports-template-standard  should render correctly:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
      at [object Object].dispatchSidebarExists (/src/sports-template-standard.jsx:80:56)
      at [object Object].componentWillMount (/src/sports-template-standard.jsx:49:14)
      at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:210:12)
      at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
      at [object Object].ReactShallowRenderer._render (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:362:14)
      at [object Object].ReactShallowRenderer.render (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:344:8)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/test/sports-template-standard-tests.js:31:25)
      at callFn (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:286:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:279:7)
      at Runner.runTest (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:421:10)
      at \node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:341:14)
      at \node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:351:7
      at next (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:283:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:319:5)
```

**test cases**

```
`javascript`
import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import initializeJsDom from './test-utils/dom.js';
import {SportsPageClasses} from 'sports-css-grids';
import sportsMockUpStandard from '../src/sports-template-standard';

describe('shallow renderer tests for sports-template-standard ', function() {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    console.log("shallowRenderer" + JSON.stringify(shallowRenderer));

    it('should render correctly', () => {

        //var rightPanel ="some string";
        var layout ="some string";        
        var hasSidebar = function(){
            done();
        }
        console.log("here1");
        //this.props.layout.rightPanel.exists = 'some value';

        shallowRenderer.render(<sportsMockUpStandard
            headerClass='8887' 
            layout= {{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}} 
            sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} 
            title={"Demo"} />);

        // shallowRenderer.render(<sportsMockUpStandard

        //layout= {{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}}  />); 

        console.log("here2");
    });
});
```

**snippet code**

```
`javascript`    
dispatchSidebarExists(props) {
    let hasSidebar = !!props.sidebar;

    // infinite loop without this check
    if (hasSidebar !== this.props.layout.rightPanel.exists) {
        this.props.dispatch(setSportsCornerState({
            exists: hasSidebar
        }));
    }
}
```

**whole code**

````
export function setSportsCornerState(stateString) { return { type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL', stateString }; } ```
````

**new warning**

```
 Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `sidebar` supplied to `sportsMockUpStandard`.


 // var rightPanel ="some string";
        var layout ="some string";

         var hasSidebar = function(){
          //  done();
    }
        console.log("here1");
      //  this.props.layout.rightPanel.exists = 'some value';

        shallowRenderer.render(<sportsMockUpStandard
            headerClass='8887' 
            layout= {{rightPanel: {exists: hasSidebar}, text: 'hello world'}} 
            sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} 
            title={"Demo"} dispatch={hasSidebar} />);
```

Comment: @all why did you guys mark it negative...since I tried and pasted my code too :(

Comment: Can you post the code for `setSportsCornerState`? Does it return an object with a payload property? That doesn't look like an redux dispatch I've ever seen, they usually have an action and a payload, but I guess that stuff is returned by that method? Because if not, I'm betting that's your issue.

Comment: @OceansOnPluto hey thanks for your reply...I am little bit confused about your explaination...providing my code below 

```
export function setSportsCornerState(stateString) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL',
        stateString
    };
}
```

Comment: @OceansOnPluto i am beginner in js...can you update in my test case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your reducer is calling the property `exists` on the state, right? But it's not finding it? That's because you've dispatched an object but haven't added the payload.

Your code says you dispatch the object like this.

```
setSportsCornerState(stateString) { 
    return { type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL', stateString }; 
}
```

Given your code here....

```
this.props.dispatch(setSportsCornerState({
            exists: hasSidebar
        }));
```

.... That means the object you're dispatching is going to look like this.

```
 { type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL', {exists: hasSidebar} }
```

I'm actually not sure how the property get's named in this case, if you have an object and another object inside it without a property name. That being said, this is what your object SHOULD look like.

```
     { type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL', payload: {exists: hasSidebar} }
```

If you want to pass information to a reducer, you need to pass it through the payload property. Your object should always have a payload, and that payload should always be an object. Change your code to the following.

```
export function setSportsCornerState(stateString) { 
    return { type: 'SET_HEADERPANEL', payload: stateString }; 
}
```

This set's the payload object as the information you want to pass. Then your reducer, should look for the `exists` property on the payload object.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in the below gist for the test case https://gist.github.com/js08/dfeab2df8b68240297eb

Comment: I mean, that's not really how this site works, generally you try it and see if it works and if it does you accept my answer. But, you need to change the code. the test case will always fail unless you add the payload property, because redux was not set up to work any other way.

Comment: ok...but this line in test code how should I need to modify

``` 
       sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} 

```

Comment: Just change the function to what I detailed in the last code block and see if that works.

Comment: ok...but this line in test code how should I need to modify ``` sidebar= {[{hasSidebar},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} ```

Comment: You don't change that code. There's nothing wrong with THAT code, however it's calling the render method, which is calling a method to dispatch something to a reducer, and that something is being dispatched wrong. The code I gave you should fix the error. There's nothing wrong with the line you've shown.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i fixed the error by making change in test case but not sure how to fix the warning...providing warning and code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sa1akk0v/

Comment: That comes from         `this.dispatchSidebarExists(this.props);` in your componentDidMount. You have to selectively pass the props in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106535/discussion-between-oceansonpluto-and-texi-rv).

Comment: it would be great if you tell me how to fix the warning in my test case jsfiddle.net/8kmh1rzw/1