# Algolia: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined at Object.syncAlgoliaWithFirebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I'm trying to use Algolia with Firebase Functions, but I get this error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined at Object.syncAlgoliaWithFirebase (/workspace/node_modules/algolia-firebase-functions/dist/index.js:79:23)*
I followed the steps on the npm algolia-firebase-functions library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/algolia-firebase-functions).

This is my Firebase function code:

```node
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.firestore()
const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");
const algoliaFunctions = require('algolia-firebase-functions');


const algolia = algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.app,
                              functions.config().algolia.key);
const index = algolia.initIndex(functions.config().algolia.index);


exports.indexBesedilo = functions.firestore.document('besedila/{document}').onCreate((change, context) =>
    algoliaFunctions.syncAlgoliaWithFirebase(index, change)
)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/fobo66/algolia-firebase-functions#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20using%20Firebase%20Cloud%20Firestore%2C%20you%20can%20use%20the%20following%20code%3A), if you're using Firebase Cloud Firestore,  you should use `syncAlgoliaWithFirestore` instead of `syncAlgoliaWithFirebase`.

Your function becomes:

```js
exports.indexBesedilo = functions.firestore.document('besedila/{document}').onCreate((change, context) =>
    algoliaFunctions.syncAlgoliaWithFirestore(index, change)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed it to Firestore, but now I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined at Object.syncAlgoliaWithFirestore (/workspace/node_modules/algolia-firebase-functions/dist/index.js:92:23)

Comment: I suggest you to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36051654/9330208) in which they discuss a similar issue. It looks like the payload does not have the property ```exists```.